# A question about the topological sphere theorem

Tags: riemannian-geometry

I have referred Wikipedia on the topological sphere theorem:If $M$ is a complete, simply-connected, $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold with sectional curvature taking values in the interval $(1,4]$ then $M$ is homeomorphic to the $n$-sphere. 
Actually, it's true for all sectional curvatures in the interval $(1/4c,c]$,where $c$ is any positive constant. So why Wikipedia gives so special situation? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can scale by a constant, not really any benefit to the parameter $c$

Comment: @WillJagy you mean change metric g by scaling a constant?

Comment: Yes. Should be in Cheeger and Ebin

Comment: @WillJagy Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: If a special case is trivially generalizable then I would say it is okay to restrict to it. It is like saying "Wikipedia states that $(n^2)'=2n$ but does not say that more generally $(cn^2)'=2cn$".

Comment: @M.Winter yeah, it's reasonable, thank you